# How to add new data and keep old existing data

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm nearly done making my mobile game and I have have a DATA script using what is shown in [this](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/persistence-saving-and-loading-data) video. I have a list which holds the values of different challenges that the player can complete. How would I update the game so that I can add more challenges whilst still keeping the old data.

(The challenge data basically contains whether it has been completed and how far off being completed it is)

I have had a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/version-tolerant-serialization) guide but I don't quite understand it. I'm new to serialization.

Thank you in advance :)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

[System.Serializable]
public class XMLManager : MonoBehaviour {

    public static XMLManager dataManagement;

    public gameData data;


    void Awake()
    {
        //File.Delete(Application.dataPath + "/StreamingFiles/XML/item_data.xml");
        System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("MONO_REFLECTION_SERIALIZER", "yes");
        dataManagement = this;
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);

    }


    public void SaveData()
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(gameData));
        System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("MONO_REFLECTION_SERIALIZER", "yes");
        FileStream stream = new FileStream(Application.dataPath + "/StreamingFiles/XML/item_data.xml", FileMode.Create);
        serializer.Serialize(stream, data);
        stream.Close();
    }
    public void LoadData()
    {
        System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("MONO_REFLECTION_SERIALIZER", "yes");
        if (File.Exists(Application.dataPath + "/StreamingFiles/XML/item_data.xml"))
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(gameData));
            FileStream stream = new FileStream(Application.dataPath + "/StreamingFiles/XML/item_data.xml", FileMode.Open);
            data = serializer.Deserialize(stream) as gameData;
            stream.Close();

        }
        else
        {
            print("SaveData");
            SaveData();
        }


    }
}

[System.Serializable]
public class gameData
{


    public List<ChallengeStatus> Challenges;
    public int HighScore;
    public int CoinsCollected;
    public List<bool> Unlocked;
    public int GamesPlayed;
    public int currentChallenge;

}
[System.Serializable]
public class ChallengeStatus
{


    public int id;
    public string title;
    public int current;
    public int max;
    public int reward;
    public bool completed;
    public bool claimed;



}
```

Comment: Best thing would be to have them in an external database or e.g. Xml file. Then you don't even have to recompile but just change the file/database

Comment: @derHugo thank you for that. I have now changed it to an XML file but I still don't quite understand how I can add new data to the file on their phone and keep the old file. Apologies if this is an easy task but I just can't figure it out. I have added my code up above. Because when it loads the file it loads all the data from the old file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should have a look at [Unity XML Serialization](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Saving_and_Loading_Data:_XmlSerializer) and use proper attributes. You don't totally need them (except maybe the `[XmlRoot]`) but they let you customize your Xml file. If not provided Unity uses the variable names and uses sub-elements instead of attributes. However afaik this works only for primitives (`int`, `float`, `string`, `bool`, etc) and lists of them not for your own class `ChallengeStatus`. So at least for the list of your class you have to provide attributes:

```
[System.Serializable]
[XmlRoot("GameData")]
public class GameData
{
    [XmlArray("Challenges")]
    [XmlArrayItem("ChallengeStatus)]
    public List<ChallengeStatus> Challenges;

    //...
}
```

---

Now I don't really understand why you need to keep the old XML file when saving a new one but if you want to keep the current file I would add an `int FileCounter` .. ofcourse not in the same XML file ;) Might be e.g. via [PlayerPrefs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html) or a second simple text file only including the number or something similar.

Note it is better/saver to use [Path.Combine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=netframework-4.6) for concatenate systempaths) - the overload taking an array of strings requires .Net4. Something like

```
private string FilePath 
{
    get
    {
        //TODO first load / read the FileCounter from somewhere

        var paths = {
        Application.dataPath, 
        "StreamingFiles", 
        "XML", 

        // here you get from somewhere and use that global FileCounter
        string.Format("item_data_{0}.xml", FileCounter)};

        return Path.Combine(paths);
    }
}
```

Than you can increase that global `FileCounter` everytime you save the file.

```
public void SaveData()
{
    //TODO somehow increase the global value
    // store to PlayerPrefs or write a new file or ...
    FileCounter += 1;

    System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("MONO_REFLECTION_SERIALIZER", "yes");   

    // better use the "using" keyword for streams
    // use the FilePath field to get the filepath including the filecounter
    using(FileStream stream = new FileStream(FilePath, FileMode.Create))
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(gameData))
        serializer.Serialize(stream, data);
    }
}
```

And read the file with the current `FileCounter` without increasing it

```
public void LoadData()
{
    System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("MONO_REFLECTION_SERIALIZER", "yes");

    if (File.Exists(FilePath))
    {
        // better use a "using" block for streams
        // use the FilePath field to get the filepath including the filecounter
        using(FileStream stream = new FileStream(FilePath, FileMode.Open))
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(gameData));
            data = serializer.Deserialize(stream) as gameData;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        print("SaveData");
        SaveData();
    }
}
```

---

**Hint 1**: 
As soon as you provide a constructor for your classes e.g.

```
public GameData(List<ChallengeStatus> challenges)
{
    Challenges = challenges;
}
```

than you always have to also provide a default constructor (even if it does nothing)

```
public GameData(){ }
```

**Hint 2:** 
You should always initialize your lists:

```
public class GameData
{
    public List<ChallengeStatus> Challenges = new List≤ChallangeStatus>();
    //...

    public List<bool> Unlocked = new List<bool>();

    //...
}
```

**Hint 3**:
Btw you don't need that `[System.Serializable]` for `XmlManager` since it inherits from `MonoBehaviour` which already is serializable anyway.